# How to get access to the progressBar?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

In my program on the WindowsForms I have a **MainForm**, which contains **ProgressBar**. In the **ChildForm** I want to change it's value, but I'm getting an error:

*"int" does not contain a definition for "Value". Unable to find an extension method "Value", taking first argument of type "int" (missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

**Main Form:**

```
public int ProgressBar5
{
    get { return progressBar5.Value; }
    set { progressBar5.Value = value; }
}
```

**Child Form:**

```
static MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    mainForm.ProgressBar5.Value++; // Error
}
```

**Edit1:**
In the main form the value of the **progressBar5** is always equals **1**. What can be reason of it? I thought, that **static** can fix it.

**Main Form:**

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Child child = new Child();
    child.ShowDialog();
    MessageBox.Show(progressBar5.Value.ToString()); // All time Value = 1
}
```

Comment: Do you have a ProgressBar called ProgressBar5 as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ProgressBar5` property already takes care of accessing the `Value` property of the progress bar.  It doesn't return the progress bar, but rather the current progress.  This means that the caller doesn't need to access the `Value` property of the result (since there is none).

Just write:

```
mainForm.ProgressBar5++;
```

Of course, for clarity's sake, it would probably be better to call such a property `CurrentProgress` rather than `ProgressBar` because it *doesn't* return a progress bar, it returns (or sets) the current progress.

Of course, better still would be for the child for to have no knowledge of the main form at all.  Rather than passing in the main form itself the child form can accept an `IProgress` instance.  It can then report progress to *whomever* is creating this form, whether that be your main form, or anything else.  The main form is then responsible for doing whatever it wants when progress is reported, which it can define in either an event handler or a delegate passed into the `Progress` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two variables with similar names, causing quite a bit of confusion. When you try and access the `ProgressBar5` variable you are actually getting the int property you declared in the first snippet.

Since int does not have a `Value` property, you get the compile time error. Change your code to:

```
static MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    mainForm.ProgressBar5++; // Fixed!
}
```

Comment: He *doesn't* have two variables of the same name.  There is no name collisions in the code provided.  Remember C# is case sensitive.  If this was VB there'd be a collision.

Comment: @Servy, In the response to my comment, he said he has a ProgressBar called "ProgressBar5" after reading his first code snippet again, I realize he didn't intend to match my case. I will edit to fix.